# problema con la descarga del pom.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, descarga

estoy teniendo problemas con el spring initializr, cargo todo selecciono dependencias y cuando descargo el zip el pom.xml no esta, alguna idea de que puedo hacer? [image: selecciono todo]

[image: lo que me descarga]

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. El fichero pom.xml es utilizado por maven, por lo que selecciona maven en lugar gradle-groovy en la sección Project.

Comment: Debes crear tu proyecto seleccionando maven si deseas que te genere el archivo pom.xml ,buena suerte